# TMobile G2X as dev phone

Tags: adb, lg-optimus-2x, t-mobile-g2x, lg-p999

I'm trying to use my T Mobile locked LG G2X as a dev phone while I wait for my GNex4. I can't get the phone to be found by ADB. I installed the p999 driver from LG's website. This didn't help anything. I tried adding the VID manually to `adb_usb.ini`. The VID I found in device manager was `USB\VID_17EF&PID_4807&REV_3134` so I entered the line `0x17EF` into the file. This didn't help either.

How can I get the p999 working as a dev phone?

Does anyone know the right VID entry for the p999?

Also, when I plug the phone into my Windows 7 computer, the phone charges, but does not prompt any sort of device discovery message from windows... does this indicate some other problem? My USB ports definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicions from the last part of my question were correct... Unbeknownst to me I was using a micro-usb "charge only" cable (I snagged it from a friend)... I didn't even know they made such a useless thing. Some of these are actually MORE expensive then a normal cable.